# Get distance and angle from OrbitControl's target

Tags: three.js

I'm making a 3D earth explorer using three js and orbit control in which I want to be able to zoom in and open a external map at that location.

I therefore need the distance from the target as well as the current camera angle (to convert to long lat later). However, the orbit control library doesn't provide methods for getting this information.

I suppose that this is a simple 3D trigonometry problem but I can't wrap my head around it. How would you do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const polarAngle = controls.getPolarAngle();
const azimuthalAngle = controls.getAzimuthalAngle();
const distance = controls.object.position.distanceTo( controls.target );
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6109/

`three.js R92`

Comment: Awesome! Any idea on how to convert those angles to GPS coordinates ?